# How to select count between start to (start+length)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table`
(
    `start`  int NOT NULL,
    `length` int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `new_table`
VALUES (5, 6),
       (11, 1),
       (21, 10),
       (11, 8),
       (13, 18);
```

How the following result appears when creating a table as above.

```
|-----------|----------|
|   1~10    |     1    |
|-----------|----------|
|   11~20   |     4    |
|-----------|----------|
|   21~30   |     2    |
|-----------|----------|
|   31~40   |     2    |
```

This is the result of counting if the value is included between start plus length.

**e.g. : start=5, length=6**

This means 5(start)~11(start+lenght)

> 5<=10 is true

<kbd>1~10</kbd> + 1

> 11<=20 is true

<kbd>11~20</kbd> + 1

**e.g. : start=21, length=10**

This means 21(start)~31(start+lenght)

> 21<=30 is true

<kbd>21~30</kbd> + 1

> 31<=40 is true

<kbd>31~40</kbd> + 1

**e.g. : start=13, length=18**

This means 13(start)~31(start+lenght)

> (13-20) between (13-31) is included in numbers less than 20.

<kbd>11~20</kbd> + 1

> (21-30) between (13-31) is included in numbers less than 30.

<kbd>21~30</kbd> + 1

> 31 between (13-31) is included in numbers less than 30.

<kbd>30~40</kbd> + 1

I've seen how to implement this via googling, but in the end I didn't get the result.
So I tried to implement it further, but it was not enough for me.

Ask for help

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. I cannot understand what you mean: can you rewrite the question?

Comment: Lime and limpid green, the sound surrounds the icy waters under

Comment: what is >=40 ? is there any row in that case?

Comment: When it starts with 5 and has the length 6  the result should be 11 and it is clearly abiuve 10  but why 20? Do you have a formula that could explaon it better or at least write the result also for the other rows maybe that could show a deterministic way

Comment: @Sterconium Corrected the example! :)

Comment: @Strawberry I cant understand. Sorry :(

Comment: Are you aware that `>=` means 'greater than or equal to'?

Comment: Also, your data set has 10 numbers. But your result set only has 9.

Comment: And I don't understand why there are two results in 21-30.

Comment: @Strawberry Please see updated question

Comment: No discernible improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to categorize (`start + length`) into different groups?  If so, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT '>=' || TRIM(length_group), COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN total_length >= 40 THEN '40' -- Evaluate to true for first match
         WHEN total_length >= 30 THEN '30'
         WHEN total_length >= 20 THEN '20'
         WHEN total_length >= 10 THEN '10'
    END AS length_group
  FROM new_table
) src
GROUP BY length_group
```

**Update**
I think I understand what you're trying to get now.  You want to get the ranges of which your `(start + length)` interval falls into.  Is that correct?  If so, give this a try:

```sql
WITH intervals(start, end) AS (
  SELECT 1, 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 21, 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 31, 40
)
SELECT val_group, COUNT(*) AS group_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(iv.start AS CHAR(3)), '~', CAST(iv.end AS CHAR(3))) AS val_group,
    iv.start
  FROM new_table src
  INNER JOIN intervals iv ON src.start BETWEEN (iv.start - src.length) AND iv.end
) src
GROUP BY val_group
ORDER BY MAX(start), group_count
;
```

It would be much easier using native data types / functions like `INTERVAL` and `OVERLAP`, but it doesn't seem like `MySql` has that functionality yet.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wSGPMUpCkkFZWxXrytEMZz/2)

Comment: I want categorize **start between (start+length)** into diffrent groups

Comment: Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks and this query also works


`SELECT CONCAT(b.\`seq\`, '~', b.\`seq\`+10) AS result_range, COUNT(b.\`seq\`) as cnt FROM \`seq_10_to_50_step_10\` b RIGHT OUTER JOIN \`new_table\` a ON b.\`seq\` BETWEEN CEIL(a.\`start\` / 10) * 10 AND CEIL((a.\`start\` + a.\`length\`) / 10) * 10 GROUP BY b.\`seq\`;`

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad you got it to work.